# AsyncEventHandler - Real Time System Java

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, real-time

Im trying to make a simulation program in which:

- A can is passed on to a conveyor
- the can is filled
- the can is checked
- if the can is damaged, it will be removed from the conveyor

errors:

```
Exception in thread "RealtimeThread[pri=20,aperiodic]" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at assignment$Sensor.run(assignment.java:99)
at javax.realtime.RealtimeThread$Logic.run(RealtimeThread.java:244)
at javax.realtime.MemoryArea.enter(MemoryArea.java)
at javax.realtime.MemoryArea.enterInternal(MemoryArea.java:1472)
at javax.realtime.RealtimeThread$Logic.run(RealtimeThread.java:230)
```

I want to use the `AsyncEventHandler` to trigger a code if the can is damaged but it gives a NullPointerException error if the can is found damaged on the first try however the code works fine if the can is not damaged on the first loop.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.realtime.*;

public class realtime{

    AsyncEvent damage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        realtime a = new realtime();
    }

    public realtime() {

        Can can = new Can(1);

        Conveyer conveyer = new Conveyer(can);
        Sensor Sensor = new Sensor(can);
        Grabber grabber = new Grabber(can, Sensor);

        ReleaseParameters relConveyer = new PeriodicParameters(new RelativeTime(1000,0));
        ReleaseParameters relSensor = new PeriodicParameters(new RelativeTime(1000,0));

        conveyer.setReleaseParameters(relConveyer);
        Sensor.setReleaseParameters(relSensor);

        conveyer.start();
        Sensor.start();

        damage = new AsyncEvent();
        damage.setHandler(grabber);

    }

    class Can {

        int id;
        boolean filled;
        boolean damaged;

        public Can(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void isFilled(boolean status) {
            this.filled = status;                   //Print if the Can is filled
        }

        public void isDamaged(boolean status) {
            this.damaged = status;          
        }

    }

    class Conveyer extends RealtimeThread {

        Can can;

        Random random = new Random();

        public Conveyer(Can can) {
            this.can = can;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {                         //While loop can be used to repeat

            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Can " + can.id + " has entered the conveyer");
                System.out.println("Can " + can.id + " is being filled");
                can.isFilled(true);                     //Sleep to give time to fill
                System.out.println("Can " + can.id + " is filled");
                System.out.println("Can " + can.id + " is being scanned");
                can.isDamaged(random.nextBoolean());
                try {
                    waitForNextRelease();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {}
            }

        }

    }

    class Sensor extends RealtimeThread{

        Can can;

        public Sensor(Can can) {
            this.can = can;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {                         //While loop can be used to repeat

            while(true) {
                if(can.damaged) {
                    System.out.println("Can " + can.id + " is Damaged!");
                    damage.fire();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Can " + can.id + " is moved to Stage 2");
                }
                try {
                    waitForNextRelease();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {}
            }

        }

    }

    class Grabber extends AsyncEventHandler {

        Can can;
        RealtimeThread rtt;
        boolean damaged = false;

        public Grabber(Can can, RealtimeThread rtt) {
            this.can = can;
            this.rtt = rtt;
        }

        public void handleAsyncEvent() {

            System.out.println("Can " + can.id + " is disposed");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How about giving us a hint, like telling us which line of your code is throwing the `NullPointerException`? Maybe you can also post the stack trace for that same `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @Abra Thank you for your comment, i have edited my code and added the errors i was receiving

Comment: Can you tell us which is line 99 of file `assignment.java` ?

Comment: @Abra its " damage.fire() " under the Sensor class

Comment: You call `Sensor.start()` **before** you assign a value to `damage` in the constructor for class `realtime`. But you only access `damage` in method `run()` of class `Sensor` if the can is damaged. So if your first can is damaged, you are accessing `damage` before you have assigned it a value. Hence it is null and therefore you get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Abra Thanks for pointing out my stupid mistake, fixed it now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a default constructor for your `Can` class. So in your `Conveyor` class you have `Can can;` This probably gives you the `NullPointerException`. Just add another constructor to your Can class like so:

```
public Can() {};
```

Comment: I do have a constructor in my Can class, it is where the id is specified

Comment: But in order to construct that object it has to have an int passed as a parameter. In your other classes you try to construct a Can object without passing an int parameter. You do not have a constructor to do that.